# Join two regex from sed

Tags: regex, sed

I'm trying to replace all words with sed between two `/` characters that is in a line which begins with a `+` character. I can find the lines that interest me with the following grep:

```
grep -e "^+" add_prefix.patch | grep -e "/myString/
```

I would to replace the word "myString" with the word "otherString". Can I somehow join the above two regular expressions in sed?

Comment: ([Useless use of `cat`.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat))

Comment: Somehow it looks a bit more readable to me than `grep -e "^+" add_prefix.patch | grep -e "/myString/"`

Comment: ‘Readable’ to some, perhaps. An eyesore to others.

Comment: OK, edited question.

Comment: That wasn't really the goal, but OK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this sed:

```
sed -i.bak '/^+/s~/myString/~/otherString/~g' my_patch.patch
```

Comment: I have no idea how do `~` thing works but it works. Thanks!

Comment: The usual delimiters for the `s` command are slashes: `s/foo/bar/`. In your case, you have slashes in the pattern, so you choose just about any other character for the delimiter. anubhava chose tilde. If you want to use, say, commas: `s,/myString/,/otherString/,g`

Comment: Thanks so much @glennjackman for edit and the helpful comment.

Comment: heh, I knew that trick works with perl 5 but didn't expect that oldschool sed could also do that. Nice.  I would just have backslashed the / but this is a way more cool way to use sed.